# Question Related to Python and Camera View

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, 3d-view, camera

I've recently been developing a rig that uses Python for UI buttons, etc. I was wondering how to make a button that would put me into a face rig camera. (something that would only be used for animation purposes)

[image: (:]

Basically, I want to be able to press this hypothetical button and be switched to a view of the rigs face, and when I press the button again, I'd go back to the 3D viewport.